# C++: how to cleanly terminate a thread without specific "interruption points"

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Is there a way to interrupt/terminate a C++ thread in such a way that all destructors are properly invoked? Boost has a [way](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-interruption-in-boost-thread-library.html) to interrupt a thread but it requires me to define "interruption points" in the code. I have no way to define "interruption points", as the code that will run in the thread is unknown.

P.S. The target architecture is Windows x64 on Intel x86_64 compiled with MSVC, so will take a WinAPI/MSVC-based solution as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the code that will run in the thread is unknown or out of your control, then there's no clean way to terminate that thread.  The only clean way to do it is to have the cooperation of the code running in that thread.

You could put that code in a separate process, if you could coordinate a way to pass whatever data between them you need to.  You could then kill the process when you want, which is mostly clean in terms of releases OS resources, but it would not be clean in the sense of having the unknown code running destructors.